# How to ask x times TCP Client for a TCP Server data's?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, android-recyclerview

### About my App

In my app there is a  **TCP Client** at the start it ask the server for a **number**, and for now it's working properly but the problem is when i have to open the connection again and ask **number** times that the **server** sent before for other data. I mean i'm trying to make a for cycle that will ask **X** times the server for data and will put them in RecyclerView.Adapter but for now the For Cycle goes in a infinity loop without stoping after **X** times .

### Example

So if i'm starting my app and it reveice number 5 from the server i will ask the server for 1st number details after i got it i will ask for 2nd number details and co.

### Here is my AsyncTask from MainActivity code where i get the **X** number from the server at the start :

```
   public static class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Client> {

    @Override
    protected Client doInBackground(String... message) {


        client = new Client(new Client.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override

            public void messageReceived(String message) {

                publishProgress(message);

            }
    });
        client.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        if(MainActivity.active){
            msgServer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
            msgServer.setText("ONLINE");

            SelfNumber = values[0];
        }
        if(help.active){
            for(int i=0; i< Integer.valueOf(SelfNumber); i++){


            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(String.valueOf(values[0]),"#");
            status = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
            receipt = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
            eur = stringTokenizer.nextToken();

                help.adapter = new SelfAdapter(("CASSA SELF N°" + Integer.toString(i+1)),"EUR: " + eur,"SC: " + receipt,help.img);
                help.selfList.add(help.adapter);
                help.adapterView.notifyDataSetChanged();

                startConnection.removeCallbacks(runnableConnection);
                startConnection.postDelayed(runnableConnection,100);

                startCashMessage.removeCallbacks(runnableCashMessage);
                startCashMessage.postDelayed(runnableCashMessage,250);


            }

        }

    }
}
```

### Handlers :

```
static Handler startConnection = new Handler();
static Runnable runnableConnection = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        new ConnectTask().execute("");
    }
};

    static Handler startCashMessage = new Handler();
static Runnable runnableCashMessage = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (help.active) {
            final Cursor cursor = myDB.fetchData();
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Client.SERVER_IP = cursor.getString(1);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            if (client != null) {
                    client.sendMessage("RICEVO DATI CASSA 1");
                }
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging what `SelfNumber` actually contains when the problem occurs? If it's just totally wrong the data sent from the server might be the culprit.

Comment: @Voltboyy actually i found the issue of the infinite loop but idk how to fix it, the issue was that i was recalling in the for `new ConnectTask().execute("");` so the AsyncTask was reacreated every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will benefit from learning to use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) / [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid).

I believe that [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/kaushikgopal/learning-rx-by-example-2) (and a [video link](https://vimeo.com/190922794)) will help you with a solution, he was presenting a solution to a similar problem.

If you never used RxJava before perhaps you should start with his first [presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/kaushikgopal/learning-rxjava-for-android-by-example) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3D0cWyNno4).

Good Luck!